# Intellij project window does not display directories/files after git checkout

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have two branches, dev and master. I was originally in dev, and in the terminal, when I checked out and pulled master, the project window did not display any of my directories or files in the window, and when I merged dev into master and re-checked out dev, it still did not display any of these files in the window, but the files were successfully merged.

*See image below:*

[image: Empty project window, No directories/files with .gitignore contents Image]

How do I re-display the local copies of my project directories and files (which should even include the git ignored files) in the project window?

Edit:

After taking another look at my local copy of the project, my .iml file was missing and .project files were missing. After copying and reloading the the files, everything is displayed now.

However...

Part of the changes I merged from dev to master were ones that would git rm -r --cached folders and files from the master and dev branches from my repository on GitLab because they were going to be ignored in the .gitignore file that I committed and pushed before the merge. I did the same for my .iml and .project, but for some reason those were the only ones removed, but the folders I did the same command for remained in my local version.

Why would that be the case?

Comment: If I was a betting man there was a name change somewhere. Have you reopen the project in intellij?

Comment: I have tried reopening the project and it doesn't reload anything :/